# Bottom Navigation - show dot under active item

Tags: android

I tried to find any similar question, but i didn't succeed. I want to use bottom navigation with my own design. It looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to place the dot under the active item icon? I tried to create the active icon already with dot in one PNG, but in this case the icon became smaller than other two.. Appreciate any help.